# How to avoid multiple subscribe which is used in other function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Consider this code:

```
// search for a location and get its geo-coordinates
   searchLocation(location: string): void {
      this.gs
         .getLocationInfo(location)
         .pipe(
            tap((data: GoogleResponse) => {
               if (data.status === 'OK') {
                  this.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                  this.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                  this.name = data.results[0].name;
               }
            }),
            map((response) => response)
         )
         .subscribe((data: GoogleResponse) => {
            if (this.mode === 'tours') {
               this.getTours();
            } else if (this.mode === 'guides') {
               this.getLocalGuides();
            }
         });
   }

   getTours(): void {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.ds.setLoadingStatus(this.isLoading);
      this.router.navigate(['/tours-view']);

      this.ts.getTourByPoiLocation(this.lng, this.lat).subscribe((tours: Tour[]) => {
         this.tours = tours;
         this.ds.setTours(this.tours);
         this.gs.setLocationName(this.name);
      });
   }
```

First I make an HTTP Request to Google using the Geocoordinate API to get the Geometry and save the data within the `tap` operator and then I'm using `subscribe` as this is an observable. (I also don't even use `data: GoogleResponse` in the subscribe.)

Within the `subscribe` I call the method `getTours()` to get some places saved in my DB with the latitude and longitude. I make another request to my server to retrieve the data. As this is an observable as well, I used `subscribe` again.

Everything works but I want to ask if there is any optimization to this code.
I think I did some bad practices especially the subscribe in the subscribe.

Can I solve this with `mergeMap` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question and your code it seems to me that you want to do the following:

- get location info invoking `getLocationInfo`
- once the response from `getLocationInfo` is received (more precisely, when the Observable returned by `getLocationInfo` emits), set some state attributes based on the values of the response received (if the condition `data.status === 'OK'` is true)
- after this, decide (based on the `mode` value) whether to trigger the execution of the `getTours` or `getLocalGuides` method
- in the case you trigger the execution of the `getTours` (i.e. if `mode === 'tours'`), you set some state, navigate to a new page and you trigger the execution of another Observable, the one returned by `getTourByPoiLocation`, and use the value emitted by this Observable to set some more state attributes with the response received
- the function `getTourByPoiLocation` actually receives as input parameters properties of the value emitted by the Observable returned by `getLocationInfo` (in your code it uses the `this.lng, this.lat` which are set based on the value emitted by the Observable returned by `getLocationInfo`)
- it is not clear what happens in case the method `getLocalGuides` is executed: this method can either execute another Observable or can run some standard synchronous logic; I assume it executes another Observable

If this understanding is right, I would try something along these lines

```
searchLocation(location: string): void {
  this.gs
    .getLocationInfo(location)
    .pipe(
       tap((data: GoogleResponse) => {
           if (data.status === 'OK') {
              this.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
              this.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
              this.name = data.results[0].name;
           }
        }),
        // use concatMap operator to execute the next Observable 
        // after the upstream Observable has notified something
        // We use the value emitted (of type GoogleResponse) to pass
        // the input parameters to the getTourByPoiLocation function
        concatMap((data: GoogleResponse) => {
          if (this.mode === 'tours') {
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.ds.setLoadingStatus(this.isLoading);
            this.router.navigate(['/tours-view']);
            // here we return the next Observable - concatMap requires, as
            // input, a function that returns an Observable
            return this.ts.getTourByPoiLocation(data.lng, data.lat)
             .pipe(
                tap((tours: Tour[]) => {
                  this.tours = tours;
                  this.ds.setTours(this.tours);
                  this.gs.setLocationName(this.name);
                })
             );
          }
          if (this.mode === 'guides') {
            // return the Observable that executes the logic for this case
            return functionThatReturnsTheObservableForGuides()
          }
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

You can factorize the code for the `this.mode === 'tours'` case in its own method, like this

```
getTours(lng, lat) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.ds.setLoadingStatus(this.isLoading);
  this.router.navigate(['/tours-view']);
  return this.ts.getTourByPoiLocation(data.lng, data.lat)
   .pipe(
     tap((tours: Tour[]) => {
       this.tours = tours;
       this.ds.setTours(this.tours);
       this.gs.setLocationName(this.name);
     })
   );
}
```

and end up with this version

```
searchLocation(location: string): void {
  this.gs
    .getLocationInfo(location)
    .pipe(
       tap((data: GoogleResponse) => {
           if (data.status === 'OK') {
              this.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
              this.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
              this.name = data.results[0].name;
           }
        }),
        // use concatMap operator to execute the next Observable 
        // after the upstream Observable has notified something
        // We use the value emitted (of type GoogleResponse) to pass
        // the input parameters to the getTourByPoiLocation function
        concatMap((data: GoogleResponse) => {
          if (this.mode === 'tours') {
            return getTours(data.lng, data.lat);
          }
          if (this.mode === 'guides') {
            // return the Observable that executes the logic for this case
            return functionThatReturnsTheObservableForGuides()
          }
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

I could not set up an equal example, so there may be syntactical errors, but I hope this give an idea about how to avoid nested subscriptions in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `mergeMap` like this:

```
// search for a location and get its geo-coordinates
   searchLocation(location: string): void {
      this.gs
         .getLocationInfo(location)
         .pipe(
            tap((data: GoogleResponse) => {
               if (data.status === 'OK') {
                  this.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                  this.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                  this.name = data.results[0].name;
               }
            }),
            mergeMap((response: GoogleResponse) => this.ts.getTourByPoiLocation(this.lng, this.lat))
         )
         .subscribe((tours: Tour[]) => {
            if (this.mode === 'tours') {
               this.getTours(tours);
            } else if (this.mode === 'guides') {
               this.getLocalGuides();
            }
         });
   }

   getTours(tours: Tour[]): void {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.ds.setLoadingStatus(this.isLoading);
      this.router.navigate(['/tours-view']);

      this.tours = tours;
      this.ds.setTours(this.tours);
      this.gs.setLocationName(this.name);

   }
```

Now you just have one subscribe

Comment: It's not working. Now my tours are undefined. I think there is something wrong with the call to retrieve my tours